# Tensorflow object detection api for web element detection - Not getting correct predictions

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, object-detection

I am using Tensorflow object detection api to create a custom detector for web application - web elements detection

I have managed to use "faster_rcnn_resnet101" for transfer learning. Trained on GCP using 9 workers for 10hrs [Managed to train for 9713 steps - anymore I would have run out of my GCP credits ]

Loss had stabilised at 0.04 - 0.02 [Loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i38yc.png). And when i check on images tab [Tensorboard]. I can see predictions happening consistently.

1. My input images are snapshots of google.com
2. Image size - 3360 X 1768
3. Training - 17 Classes[1 for each web element]
4. 50 augmented images per class
5. training/Test data - random distribution of the 50 images between training/testing.

After the training for 9713 steps. I stopped the training as loss was pretty stable.here are the metrics[detectionboxes_precision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wATq.png)
[detectionboxes_recall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwrMz.png)
[loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6uG5.png)
I exported the checkpoint in to a frozen_graph for prediction.

When i give it a webcam feed or an image of google.com. It predicts objects completely off the mark.At times completely outside the web page[Webcam feed for prediction.Classes predicted outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiJNc.jpg)

What can i do to get this right.